# Android 8 Broadcast Intents Changes

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wifip2p

I have an android app that uses WiFiP2P for data transfer and it was required for the app to listen for broadcast intents like `"android.net.wifi.p2p.DISCOVERY_STATE_CHANGE"` or `"android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE"` even when the app is closed(Removed from recent apps screen). Everything worked fine before Android 8 Oreo as it allowed for manifest declared broadcast intents. But now it is a problem in Android 8 since these are system generated broadcasts which are not whitelisted although the same things for bluetooth are.

Can anyone suggest some way to implement the same in android 8? I want the app to receive broadcasts intents even when the app is removed from the recent apps screen. Dynamically registered broadcast receivers dont work because they get unregistered as soon as the app is closed.

Thanks in advance.